# SQL: count number of times a 'churn' occurs in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I have the following SQLite DB table `app_vendor`:

```
app | vendor | active
---------------------
123 |   10   | 1  
123 |   20   | 0   // + 1 (10 is 1, 20 is 0)

255 |   10   | 1
255 |   20   | 0   // + 1 (10 is 1, 20 is 0)

675 |   10   | 0
675 |   20   | 0   // 0   (10 is 0, 20 is 0)
```

I would like to run a query that compares, in all occurrences of **the same app**:

- if vendor 10 is active: `1` and vendor 20 is not: `0` and
- **return a count** of how many times that happens throughout this DB table.

In the example above, it happens twice (for app 123 and app 255) so the return value should be `2`. I'm new to SQL and I have no idea how to group together by 'app', for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for all `app`s there is 1 row (top) for vendor 10 and 1 row (top) for vendor 20 then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER() counter
FROM app_vendor
WHERE vendor IN (10, 20) 
GROUP BY app
HAVING MIN(CASE WHEN vendor = 10 THEN active END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN vendor = 20 THEN active END) = 0
```

Another way to do it with `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT app FROM app_vendor WHERE vendor = 10 AND active = 1
  INTERSECT
  SELECT app FROM app_vendor WHERE vendor = 20 AND active = 0
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=980b714cd773213df719e0a8f3134338).
Results:

| counter |
| --- |
| 2 |

Comment: I just want to check I'm on the same page with what you're saying about your second query: in some rows with the same 'app_id', some 'vendors' are not present. There may be 'apps' that don't have a relation with 'vendor' 10, or 20, or both. There are also other vendors for a same app, e.g. 30, 40, 50. Is your 2nd query still valid with this further info?

Comment: @uber Reading the question again I see that you want vendor 10 to be active = 1 and vendor 20 to be active 0 strictly and not vice versa. If for an app there is only vendor 10 with active = 1 do you want that app in the results?

Comment: No. I want it specifically compared to vendor 20. Great question!

Comment: @uber also is there a case that for an app a vendor appears twice or more?

Comment: there is no case in which, for the same app, the SAME vendor appears more than once. it's only once and is either 1 or 0 for active. e.g: ```app 123, vendor 10, active 1```. this line will not show again with a different value for active

Comment: @uber then the 1st query will work. There is no need for all the other conditions. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use conditional aggregation

```
select count(*) 
from (select app
     from t
     group by app
     having max(case when vendor=10 and active=1 then 1 end) 
            + max(case when vendor=20 and active=0 then 1 end) = 2) t2
```

Comment: what is 't' and 't2'?

Comment: @uber t is whatever your table name is  and t2 is an alias for the derived table (subquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1)
  from (select * from test where vendor = 10 and active = 1) t1
  join (select * from test where vendor = 20 and active = 0) t2
    on t1.app = t2.app;
```

Comment: what's t1 and t2, should I just use it as it is in your example?

Comment: @uber t1 and t2 are just aliases (synonyms) for each of subwueries. You might use them as it is. All you need is to replace "test" table name to your table